# cordova SharePoint Authentication

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, sharepoint

I'm looking for a way to perform CRUD operations on a sharepoint list, from a apache cordova application. For that the app needs to be authenticated, any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

At a high level... you need to create a SharePoint Provider Hosted App to expose a REST API for the CRUD operations.  Your Cordova app could then consume that service.

Comment: okey, I will look into that, you know of any good examples/tutorials?